# Ubuntu 12.04 Lts Gnome 3 No Update Manager

Tags: gnome, update-manager

It bugs me to always log in to the Unity desktop to check for updates and install them. Is there any way to get the manager in gnome 3 or is there any specific command line to install the?

Comment: I get it automatically.

Comment: Ok but is there any command line to check and install updates?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Thank you. But isn't it supposed to be sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that they are set to update less frequently.

Open Software Center and click edit, then Software Sources

[image]

The click the Updates tab.

[image]

It may be that these are set to be very infrequent, and they aren't appearing because you update in unity before it gets a chance to.

[image]

There is also the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Automatically Check for Updates: Never
When there are security updates: Display Immediately
When there are other updates: Display weekly

Comment: I would have voted up the first second but I still don't have the privileges. I'm pretty much new to Ubuntu and this site :P

Comment: By the way, I also did " Sudo apt-get install gnome-packagekit " That install gave me the update manager :)

Comment: Okay, I didn't need to do that, but that's fine!