# Why Ubuntu seems progressing backwards in version 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

Unity is not stable, further we need more mouse clicks to get the same result.
No way to add launchers to panel.
With any of the Gnome flavors many functionalities are lost.
There is no easy way to create Desktop shortcuts.
Gedit crashes when opening more than 4 documents and when try to open utf-8 encodig files.
Vino server does not work.
The starting time is up to 30 seconds (after login screen).
Wireshark crashes when begins capturing data.
Xorg is updated frequently and sometimes I have to configure it by hand in the terminal to make it works (not for beginners).
The suspend mode does not work without making many tweaks.
Is a pain copying or moving files between folders using Files.
Software updater only works launching it by hand, does not starts automatically.
And many other drawbacks that I do not remember now.

Is an unpleasant experience after using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Can somebody explain me?

My system:
Desktop PC.
Processor: AMD Athlon (tm) II X3 450 Processor × 3
Memory: 4 GiB
Graphics: GeForce 6600 / PCIe / SSE2
OS Type: 64-bit
Disk: 1 TiB
Ubuntu: 14_04 3.13.0-29-generic

Answer (score 2):

> Unity is not stable

Use another DE if you want. I find it stable, until I wreck it.

> further we need more mouse clicks to get the same result

I disagree, I think it is very usable - much better than windows for a start.

> No way to add launchers to panel.

Sure it is! You can create a `.desktop` file and add it - [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) for information.

> With any of the Gnome flavors many functionalities are lost.

Again, the GNOME flavours don't have it lost, just hidden. They are designed for the less technical user.

> There is no easy way to create Desktop shortcuts.

Again, the same post - [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) for information. Just save it on the desktop.

> Gedit crashes when opening more than 4 documents and when try to open utf-8 encodig files.

File a bug report on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net)? Are these large files? Can you open them in `vi` or `nano`, or leafpad? Some large files do crash gedit.

> Vino server does not work.

Again, a bug report on File a bug report on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net). We need more information than "it doesn't work".

> The starting time is up to 30 seconds (after login screen).

Make a cup of tea? I think that's pretty impressive - all the features of a computer at your fingertips in 30 seconds?

> Wireshark crashes when begins capturing data.

Again, a bug report on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net). I would need to see logs and any error messages it gives in terminal.

> Xorg is updated frequently and sometimes I have to configure it by hand in the terminal to make it works (not for beginners).

"Make sure it works"? More info? The terminal is not hard to use - open it and copy/paste commands to it. You could start a blog to help other newbies with this problem.

> The suspend mode does not work without making many tweaks.

Fair point, I have problems with suspend. Just do the tweaks - if it is fixed fine. Otherwise  a bug report on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net) will help others. One of the amazing things about Ubuntu is that there is normally a workaround to a bug.

> Is a pain copying or moving files between folders using Files.

Umm click drag? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Right click copy/paste? What are you finding hard?

Remember you can use the `cp` command - you seem to be an experienced terminal user.

> Software updater only works launching it by hand, does not starts automatically.

Maybe your settings are wrong? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506575/ubuntu-12-04-lts-gnome-3-no-update-manager/506581#506581).

> And many other drawbacks that I do not remember now.

Well if you can't remember them, they can't be that bad. No point moaning!

I hope I've addressed some of your concerns, feel free to comment if you have any queries.